# iPad (air 2) not showing up on Finder

Tags: macos, ipad, finder, data-synchronization

I got an iPad air 2 that does not show up on Finder (running latest iOS 15.0.2) when connected with a lightning cable. I want to sync some files/photos to it and can't. I do see it just fine in Image Capture (so I can download photos but not upload), my iPhone device shows up just fine.

Macbook pro 16" 2019 MacOS 10.15.7
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed the latest Device Support Update in your Mac?

Comment: @lhf Software update says my Mac is up to date. Is there a special driver/update I need to install to see the older iPad? If so where do I find it?